# How to sum multiple fields from a UNION Query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2013

I'm currently learning how to use `MySQL` in queries and I have a dilemma.

Currently, I have 2 queries that fetch data from multiple tables. Both queries contain the same number of column fields and field names.

For simplicity, the output of the queries looks something like this:

QueryOne:

```
   FieldOne| FieldTwo | FieldThree | CountOne | CountTwo | CountThree 
    data1  |  data11  |  data111   |    3     |     0    |      0
    data2  |  data22  |  data222   |    0     |     1    |      0
    data3  |  data33  |  data333   |    0     |     0    |      2
    data4  |  data44  |  data444   |    0     |     4    |      0
    data5  |  data55  |  data444   |    0     |     0    |      1
```

QueryTwo:

```
   FieldOne| FieldTwo | FieldThree | CountOne | CountTwo | CountThree 
    data1  |  data11  |  data111   |    1     |     0    |      0
    data1  |  data11  |  data111   |    0     |     0    |      2
    data6  |  data66  |  data666   |    0     |     5    |      0
```

Both queries contain the same data for FieldOne-FieldThree, but may contain different values for CountOne-CountThree.

There will never be an instance where the data will contain values in all 3 fields `CountOne, CountTwo, CountThree`, but only in **ONE** of those 3 fields.

What I'm trying to do is create a separate `UNION QUERY` that has the following output:

```
   FieldOne| FieldTwo | FieldThree | CountOne | CountTwo | CountThree 
    data1  |  data11  |  data111   |    4     |     0    |      0
    data1  |  data11  |  data111   |    0     |     0    |      2
    data2  |  data22  |  data222   |    0     |     1    |      0
    data3  |  data33  |  data333   |    0     |     0    |      2
    data4  |  data44  |  data444   |    0     |     4    |      0
    data5  |  data55  |  data444   |    0     |     0    |      1
    data6  |  data66  |  data666   |    0     |     5    |      0
```

Basically, if there is more than one instance of the same data in `FieldOne`, and there is a value in the same `CountOne`, `CountTwo`, or `CountThree` for multiple instance of that same data, I'd like to get the **SUM** of that field and group that data by `FieldOne`.

However, if there is more than one instance of the same data, but it contains a value in a different `Count` field, then the query should create a separate record for it, like in the example, `data1` contains values in both `CountOne` and `CountTwo` fields.

I did something like this in `SQL View` of Access 2013 with a `UNION QUERY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM [QueryOne]
ORDER BY FieldOne
UNION SELECT *
FROM [QueryTwo]
ORDER BY FieldTwo;
```

However, with my limited knowledge, I'm stuck on how to incorporate what I want into the above code in one go, instead of creating another separate query.

Comment: I presume you also want the values for data2 in the output?

Comment: @Nick yes, missed that one...question updated

Comment: Access seems like a strange environment within which to learn MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a select with sum and group by based on the result from union

```
select  FieldOne
    , FieldTwo 
    , FieldThree 
    , sum(CountOne )
    , sum(CountTwo )
    , sum(CountThree )
from ( 
          Select FieldOne
          , FieldTwo 
          , FieldThree 
          , CountOne 
          , CountTwo 
          , CountThree 
      FROM my_view1
      UNION ALL
      Select FieldOne
          , FieldTwo 
          , FieldThree 
          , CountOne 
          , CountTwo 
          , CountThree 
      FROM my_view2
  ) T 
group by  FieldOne
    , FieldTwo 
    , FieldThree 
order by FieldOne
```

You can use UNION if you want merge distinct value or UNION ALL if you want merge all the result form the united  select  ..

and do the your  "bit confusion " about the use for query in union subselect

```
select  FieldOne
    , FieldTwo 
    , FieldThree 
    , sum(CountOne )
    , sum(CountTwo )
    , sum(CountThree )
from ( 
          Select FieldOne
          , FieldTwo 
          , FieldThree 
          , CountOne 
          , CountTwo 
          , CountThree 
      FROM ( select col1 as FieldOne, col2 as FieldTwo .....
             from   ...  
             where 

         ) TT_A
      UNION ALL
      Select FieldOne
          , FieldTwo 
          , FieldThree 
          , CountOne 
          , CountTwo 
          , CountThree 
      FROM ( select col1 as FieldOne, col2 as FieldTwo .....
             from   ...  
             where 

         ) TT_B
  ) T 
group by  FieldOne
    , FieldTwo 
    , FieldThree 
order by FieldOne
```

Comment: sorry to ask, but this all can be done in `SQL View` of Access?

Comment: why not  .. instead of my_table1 adn my_table2  just use your view_name

Comment: @Andre  ...  correct.. many thanks .. wrong copy and paste .. answer  updated

Comment: sorry I'm a bit confused on the `SELECT` from `my_table1` and `my_table2`....my 2 queries each contain numerous tables via relationships that when combined gets `FieldOne, FieldTwo, FieldThree, CountOne, CountTwo, CountThree`...how can I use this in my `UNION QUERY`?....shouldn't I be referencing my `QueryOne` and `QueryTwo`?

Comment: answer  updated .. with  a suggestion for you subquery ..  hope is clear ..

Comment: I have tried some things, but due to my limited knowledge, I am getting nowhere and producing some weird results in the query....is it possible to talk with you in chat without bombarding here with back-to-back responses?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167499/discussion-between-scaisedge-and-pangu).